# Modifying order of a legend in ggplot by total sum observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm graphing a line plot in ggplot of numbers of migrants to a city over x years, based on country of origin. Each country is graphed as its own line, plotted on a graph against other countries, over a period of five years.

I want to order the legend by country from largest to smallest total sum of migrants over the x years, regardless of the total number of countries, instead of alphabetically as it is now.

I've tried using forcats commands such as fct_relevel, but haven't been able to find anything other than doing it manually, which can be time consuming for multiple graphs.

My data frame has variables `year`, `country`, and `number_migrants`, and each observation is a year-country pair.

```
library(tidyverse)
g <- ggplot(migrants, aes(x=year, y=number_migrants, col=country)) + 
geom_line()
```

**Current example:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need `fct_reorder`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
migrants %>%
  mutate(
    country = fct_reorder(country, number_migrants, .desc = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(migrants, aes(x=year, y=number_migrants, col=country)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Since OP doesn't give any indication of what packages they are using, you should probably add `dplyr` and `forcats` library calls. (Okay, I guess OP does mention `forcats`, but it's nice for future readers to make the dependency explicit.)

Comment: And, for reference, the `base` version is `migrants$country = reorder(migrants$country, -migrants$number_migrants)`.

Comment: I added `dplyr`.  He did specifically mention `fct_relevel`, so I assumed he was familiar with `forcats`.  `forcats` now added as well.